# ChartJS 2.7.0 updating and exporting as png

Tags: jquery, chart.js

So I have a ChartJS chart and I am trying to update the title of this chart, thus far I have made it work and display the new title! (woohoo).

However my issue comes when I try to export the chart with its new title showing.

I am converting to a base64 png. Creating an a-tag, programatically clicking the a-tag, then removing the a-tag and finally changing the title back to the old title.

Up to the point where I am trying to save the chart with new title as a base64 png everything works. Then the new title is not on the exported .png

```
function downloadImage($id) {
console.log("");
console.log("*///// SAVING /////*");

//get the charts variable name (stored as a data-attribute on the canvas element called chart-var)
var chart_variable_name = $("#" + $id).data('chart-var');
//convert this to a usable variable instead of a string
var chart_variable = eval(chart_variable_name);

console.log("");
console.log("Get Chart Variable");
console.log(chart_variable);

//get canvas element using id passed in
var ctx = $("#" + $id);
//get data-export-title attribute (multiline title with Title, Date, Source)
var exportTitle = $(ctx).data('export-title');

console.log("");
console.log("Get Chart");
console.log(ctx);

console.log("");
console.log("Get Chart Export Title");
console.log(exportTitle);

//get the old title from the ChartJS Object (ready to use for going back to old title)
var old_title = chart_variable.options.title.text;

console.log("");
console.log("Get Chart Old Title");
console.log(old_title);

// get the exportTitle as an array, this will allow for MultiLine titles on export
arr = exportTitle.split(',');

console.log("");
console.log("Get Chart New Title");
console.log(arr);

//push String "Title" + old_title variable so we have the title added at the end of the array
arr.push("Title: " + old_title);

//set the charts title text to the new Multiline export title.
chart_variable.options.title.text = arr;

//run the update on the chart
chart_variable.update();

chart_variable = eval(chart_variable_name);

console.log("");
console.log("Get Chart Current Options");
console.log(chart_variable.options);

//convert the chart to a base64 link PNG
var newBase64 = chart_variable.toBase64Image();

//insert an <a> tag which is hidden, before the save button - irrelevant where it goes as it wont be seen but for consistency
$("<a id='" + $id + "-button-temp' style='display:none;' class='button-style' href='" + newBase64 + "' download='" + $id + ".png' >Download</a>").insertAfter($('#' + $id + '-button'));

    //programmatically find and click the <a> tag to initiate the download of the image
   ($(document).find("#" + $id + "-button-temp")[0]).click();

   //programmatically remove the <a> tag so we dont clutter the page with unecessary HTML that are hidden
   ($(document).find("#" + $id + "-button-temp")[0]).remove();

   //set chart title back to previous title
  //chart_variable.options.title.text = old_title;
}
```

Does anyone have an idea as to why this is happening...?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is happening because, when you update chart *(after changing title)* by calling the [`update()`](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/api.html#updateconfig) method, it re-renders the entire chart with an **animation**, which takes some time *(approx. 1000 ms)* to complete, making the chart update process delayed, and since this process is happening asynchronously, your image saving code executes even before the chart is updated completely, which makes the new title not show up on the exported image.

So basically, what you need is to update the chart without an animation *(synchronously)* , after changing the chart title and that could be done in either of two ways :

**1.** passing a `config` object *(argument)* to the `update` method with **`duration`** property set to **`0`** :

```
chart_variable.update({
   duration: 0
});
```

**2.** passing just **`0`** as argument to the `update` method *(see [preventing animations](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/updates.html#preventing-animations))* :

```
chart_variable.update(0);
```

[**ᴡᴏʀᴋɪɴɢ ᴅᴇᴍᴏ**](https://jsfiddle.net/uabczmxa/) **⧩**

```js
var chart_variable = new Chart(ctx, {
   type: 'line',
   data: {
      labels: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May'],
      datasets: [{
         label: 'My First Dataset',
         data: [3, 1, 4, 2, 5],
         backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 119, 290, 0.2)',
         borderColor: 'rgba(0, 119, 290, 0.6)'
      }]
   },
   options: {
      title: {
         display: true,
         text: 'Chart Title'
      },
      scales: {
         yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
               beginAtZero: true,
               stepSize: 1
            }
         }]
      }
   }
});

function downloadImage() {
   /* set new title */
   chart_variable.options.title.text = 'New Chart Title';
   chart_variable.update({
      duration: 0
   });
   // or, use
   // chart_variable.update(0);

   /* save as image */
   var link = document.createElement('a');
   link.href = chart_variable.toBase64Image();
   link.download = 'myImage.png';
   link.click();

   /* rollback to old title */
   chart_variable.options.title.text = 'Chart Title';
   chart_variable.update({
      duration: 0
   });
   // or, use
   // chart_variable.update(0);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.1/Chart.min.js"></script>

<button onclick="downloadImage();">save as image</button>
<canvas id="ctx"></canvas>
```

Comment: Works perfectly now! Such a simple solution to an otherwise annoying problem! I will assign the bounty once it allows me (29 minutes to wait!)

Comment: No problem.. Glad it helped.